# Support for XML in Jersey Client in a standalone application

Tags: jaxb, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I have a standalone application which connects to a RESTful API like this:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget target = client.target(hostWithPort).path(apiConfig.getUrl());

CreateReq request = new CreateReq();//this is annotated with @XmlRootElement

CreateResult result = target
      .request(MediaType.TEXT_XML_TYPE)
      .post(Entity.entity(request, MediaType.TEXT_XML_TYPE), CreateResult.class);
```

The problem is that I get the following an `MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException`:

```
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=text/xml, type=class com.mydomain.communication.CreateReq., genericType=class com.mydomain.communication.CreateReq.
```

According to the [Jersey Documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/2.17/media.html#xml) there must already be support for an JAXB Provider, but somehow it does no find it. I suppose I miss a dependency in my maven and some provider registration in my code. In my `pom.xml` I have only the dependency to `org.glassfish.jersey.core -> jersey-client`

Comment: `MediaType.APPLICATION_XML`? Alternatively you can use `Entity.xml(request)`

Comment: Did you change it both in the `.request()` and the `Entity`? It is the exact same error?

Comment: I have changed both in `request()` and in `Entity.entity()` to `MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE` and now the exception is still thrown, just with the new Media Type in it.

Comment: Yeah you're right. The `jersey-client` dependency doesn't pull in `jersey-media-jaxb`. After adding that as  a dependency, it works. I guess the documentation is simply referring to Jersey as a Server side framework, should support JAXB out the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah I guess the [`jersey-client`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-client) dependency doesn't pull in the required [`jersey-media-jaxb`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.media/jersey-media-jaxb). Seems to be starting from 2.16 and up.

As stated in [the migration guide](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/migration.html#mig-2.16)

> **27.2. Migrating from Jersey 2.15 to 2.16**
>
> 27.2.1.1. JAX-B providers separated from the core
>
> From version 2.16 onwards, all JAX-B providers are being bundled in a separate module.